# How they derive The Green strain tensor?

Tags: stresses, deformation

[image]in this paper
they give the deformation tensor and the green lagrange tensor without explanation
i have some difficulties with tensor calculus ,Especially dyadic product
can some one explain it in explicit and detail , how they get E11 : The Green strain tensor ?
how we derive N dyad N or g dyad G[image]

Comment: Was there a diagram? What have you done so far to analyse this?

Comment: yes there is a diagram